# Android DataStore Flow and LiveData | all preferences receive update although only one preference is updated

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, datastore

I have an Architecture Components [DataStore](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore) in my App. In this DataStore I have multiple preferences.
Following a snippet of two preferences.

```
val calibrationFactorFlow: Flow<Float> = context.dataStore.data.map {
        preferences -> preferences[PreferencesKeys.CALIBRATION_FACTOR] ?: AppConstants.DEFAULT_CALIBRATION_FACTOR
}
suspend fun saveCalibrationToDataStore(calibrationFactor: Float) {
    context.dataStore.edit { preferences ->
        preferences[PreferencesKeys.CALIBRATION_FACTOR] = calibrationFactor
    }
}


val scaleFactorMetricFlow: Flow<Int> = context.dataStore.data.map {
        preferences -> preferences[PreferencesKeys.SCALE_FACTOR_METRIC] ?: AppConstants.DEFAULT_SCALE_FACTOR_METRIC
}
suspend fun saveScaleFactorMetricToDataStore(scaleFactor: Int) {
    context.dataStore.edit { preferences ->
        preferences[PreferencesKeys.SCALE_FACTOR_METRIC] = scaleFactor
    }
}
```

I use the received `Flow` in my `ViewModel` as `LiveData`.

```
val calibrationFactor: LiveData<Float> = repository.calibrationFactorFlow.asLiveData()
val scaleSelectedMetricId: LiveData<Int> = repository.scaleFactorMetricFlow.asLiveData()
```

The problem is, whenever I make an update to one of these preferences in the data store all other preferences receive an update. I cannot unterstand why and I cannot find anything in the documentation.

Someone has any idea why this happens or how I can prevent all preferences from receiving an update when only one preference is updated in `LiveData / Flow`

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After further researches I found this statement in an official Android page:

*Room vs DataStore
If you have a need for partial updates, referential integrity, or large/complex datasets, you should consider using Room instead of DataStore. DataStore is ideal for small or simple datasets and does not support partial updates or referential integrity.*

So Datastore is considered as monolithic, for partial updates we have to use another object such as Room

**EDIT:**

Here is the solution: use distinctUntilChanged() method on Flow

```
    val volUpLiveData: LiveData<Int> = mContext.dataStore.data
    .map { diags ->
        diags[tagNameVolUp] ?: -1
    }.distinctUntilChanged().asLiveData()
```

Comment: Thanks. Solved it by myself a while ago. distinctUntilChanged is key here to only get notified about changes affecting this key.